# Avoiding Branch Operations in Switch Statements

Tags: c++, optimization, switch-statement

Instead of a switch statement running iterating through branch after branch, is there away to make assembly look up a list in an array for a goto statement? Or is this usually optimized in the compiler?

Such an optimization would help immensely for large switch statements with constant values.

Ex:

```
switch(test) {
case 1:
// Do something
break;
case 2:
// Do something
break;
}
```

"Optimized":

```
action_link[] = {action_1, action_2};
goto action_link[test];

action_1:
// Do Something
action_2:
// Do Something
```

Comment: Switch is usually compiler optimized

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596320/how-does-switch-compile-and-how-optimized-and-fast-is-it

Comment: Thanks for the link, sorry for the duplicate then.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will make this decision for you, based on your optimisation settings and its heuristics about what might make a good jump table.

In many simple situations, the compiler might decide that a naive test-and-jump chain would be faster or smaller than the equivalent jump table.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed what you should expect from a decent compiler. In fact, the limitations of the `switch` statement were based on making it easy to translate to a "[jump table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table)" instead of multiple  branches.  Back at the dawn of time, FORTRAN had the "computed GOTO" for the same reason.