# Does MSVC c++ compiler convert a switch statement to a lookup table to improve efficiency?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

Does MSVC compiler (Microsoft Visual Studio) does any optimization such as converting to a look-up or hash table for switch-case statements?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=vs-2019

Comment: I would be shocked and awed if it didn't

Comment: As someone who has had to decompile VS generated code I can assure you it does do switch tables and other optimisations such as 2 level switch tables, etc.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EDNynm

Comment: yes of course. It can also [generate a bit lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26124620/995714)