# Cache hit and cache miss measurements ARMV8

Tags: c, assembly, arm64, cpu-cache, armv8

I have been trying to measure cache hit and cache miss.
I have been working on a Quad core Cortex-A72 (ARM v8) 64-bit SoC @ 1.5GHz.
My c code to measure cache hit is:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/random.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
    
char *chunk;
const size_t chunk_size = 1<<30; 
    
/* FUNCTIONS */

struct timeval start_time, start_time1;  
double get_diff(){
struct timeval end_time;
            int rc = gettimeofday(&end_time, NULL);
            assert(rc == 0);
            return (end_time.tv_sec - start_time.tv_sec + (double) (end_time.tv_usec - start_time.tv_usec) / 1e6);
}
    
void print_affinity(){
        cpu_set_t mask;
        long nproc, i;
        if (sched_getaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1){
            perror("sched_getaffinity");
            assert(false);
        }
        nproc = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);
        printf("sched_getaffinity = ");
        for (i = 0; i < nproc; i++)
            printf("%d ", CPU_ISSET(i, &mask));
}
    
void bind_to_cpu (){
        cpu_set_t mask;
    
        print_affinity();
        printf("\n");
        printf("sched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
        CPU_ZERO(&mask);
        CPU_SET(0, &mask);
        if (sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask) == -1) {
            perror("sched_setaffinity");
            assert(false);
        }
        print_affinity();
        printf("\nsched_getcpu = %d\n", sched_getcpu());
}

void reset_mem(){
    memset(chunk, -1, chunk_size);
}

void initialize(size_t chunk_size){

    chunk = (char *) mmap(NULL,chunk_size, PROT_READ |  MAP_POPULATE  |PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
    assert(chunk!=MAP_FAILED);
    //initialize all bits to INIT_BIT value
    printf("Initializing memory...\n\n");
    reset_mem();

}


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    bind_to_cpu(); // pinning/binding cpu
    initialize(chunk_size);
    uint64_t temp=0 ;
    size_t offset1 = (rand() << 12) % chunk_size;
    size_t offset2 = (rand() << 12) % chunk_size;
    uint64_t *addr1 = (uint64_t*) (chunk+offset1);
    uint64_t *addr2 = (uint64_t*) (chunk+offset2);
    double time_result;
    sched_yield();
    __asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr1) :"memory");
    __asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr2) :"memory");
        
    for(int i =0; i<5000;i++){
        gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
        volatile uint64_t value;
        asm volatile ("LDR %0, [%1]\n\t"
        : "=r" (value)
        : "r" (addr1)
        );
        asm volatile ("LDR %0, [%1]\n\t"
        : "=r" (value)
        : "r" (addr2)
        );
        time_result += get_diff();
        //__asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr1) :"memory");
        //__asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr2) :"memory");   
    }
    sched_yield();
    printf("Total Time: %f\n\n", time_result);

    return 0;
}
```

The code to measure cache miss is the same but using the two flush instructions with comments:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr1) :"memory");  
__asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr2) :"memory");
```

So when i use LDR instruction everything seems to be ok, and i got the following outputs:

```
Cache hit:  Cache miss:

0.000522    0.001503
0.000558    0.001696
0.000584    0.001977
0.000712    0.002032
0.000683    0.001137
```

When i use STR instruction:

```
for(int i =0; i<5000;i++){
    gettimeofday(&start_time, NULL);
    asm volatile("str %x1, %x0" : "=m"(*addr1) : "r"(temp));
    asm volatile("str %x1, %x0" : "=m"(*addr2) : "r"(temp));
    time_result += get_diff();
    __asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr1) :"memory");
    __asm__ __volatile__("dc civac, %0\n\t" : : "r" (addr2) :"memory"); 
}
```

I got these outputs:

```
Cache hit:  Cache miss:

0.000603    0.000299
0.000287    0.000311
0.000376    0.000290
0.000311    0.000305
0.000518    0.000297
```

The differences between cache hit and cache miss are very subtle.
Why ? am i not flushing the cache in the right way ?

Comment: Your edit changed `(*addr1)` to `(*addr2)` in the store-only version, but you didn't update the timing results.  Do the times match the code in the question now, and didn't before?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, i only misspelled the code. time outputs matches the correct code

Comment: @PeterCordes reading your answer, especially: "In your second version, you're timing just the stores, not the dc civac instructions that have to do the actual work of making sure dirty data is written back to RAM", i am not sure i got all that because yes i am timing just the stores but when i use the dc civac instruction after that, the data should not be in cache anymore, right ? So the timing value using DC civac and not should be different. I know that there is a lot of noise but i expected to get a clear difference as using LDR instruction.

Comment: Data isn't in cache *before* the DC civac either, only in the store buffer.  Speed of writing data into the store buffer doesn't depend on cache hit or miss, that's part of the point of having a store buffer.  Did you not read the first sentence of my answer, or the links that follow?  That's the key to understanding this.  I edited to make it clearer.  BTW, if you have comments about my answer, you should comment under it.

Comment: @PeterCordes ok thank you! i will read it. So, how would you implement the loop to get cache hit and cache miss measurements ?

Comment: The same as your current loop, but start the clock once before the loop, and stop it once after your loop.  Exactly like my answer describes.

Comment: @PeterCordes including the DC civac! Thank you seriously, i got it!

Answer (score 2):

**High-performance CPUs have a store buffer that decouples execution of store instructions from commit to cache**, making the actual store instruction itself able to execute quickly (and speculatively) regardless of cache hit or miss.  (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105827/what-is-a-store-buffer), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876208/size-of-store-buffers-on-intel-hardware-what-exactly-is-a-store-buffer), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975540/what-is-the-difference-between-a-store-queue-and-a-store-buffer), also [Does processor stall during cache coherence operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464014/does-processor-stall-during-cache-coherence-operation))

**In your second version, you're timing *just* the stores, not the [`dc civac` instructions](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0595/h/aarch64-system-instructions/dc-civac) that have to do the actual work of making sure dirty data is written back to RAM**.  The `str` instruction itself only has to write the store data and address into the store buffer, not wait for it to commit to L1d cache.

But in your LDR version, you're timing the actual cache-miss *loads*, which can't complete until they actual read data from cache.

---

**If you time the whole loops, including the `dc civac` instructions, you'll maybe see something meaningful.**  Instead of commenting out the `dc civac` instructions, give them the address of different cache lines, not the ones you're loading or storing to.

This is especially true on cores that allow out-of-order execution.  Timing a couple instructions is not very meaningful when they can be reordered with instructions that read the clock, and when the normal state of affairs is that many instructions are "in flight".  Draining out-of-order execution with barriers so you can time something creates pretty artificial conditions, and timing overhead means you can never time the real cost of something that way.

---

`gettimeofday` is pretty high overhead compared to a cache-miss anyway; it's almost always better to construct a test that can run for many cycles, with timing outside it.

Also don't use global variables; there's no reason for not just passing an arg to `get_diff`.

Also, your load test used `volatile uint64_t value;` for the asm output for no apparent reason, forcing the compiler to emit to 2 stores to the stack for each load.  The `asm volatile` statements make sure the load happens.  Unless the CPU aggressively optimizes to discard unused load results (and not wait for them if a later instruction overwrites the register), you can just let the loads go unused.

Comment: related: http://lookview.cn/pdf/arm_v8_a_profile_architecture/main.html#%5B2062,%22XYZ%22,60,723,null%5D has a section on cache maintenance instructions for more details about the on-paper guarantees.