# Multi column grouping in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am using kendo grid to display a set of records.
But now I want to use Aggregates property to group columns and perform certain 
aggregate function on columns.

As per the below documentation,I can apply grouping on a single column,but I want to do grouping on multi column
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

Please suggest how can I acheive it.

Thanks

Comment: In group,I tried to mention more than one field object,but while rendering the grid it grouped the last field that was mentioned.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include the code?

Answer (score 10):

You need to set the [group](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-group) option of the grid's data source as array. Here is some sample code:

```
  <div id="grid"></div> 
  <script>
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
      data: [
        { name: "Pork", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" },
        { name: "Pepper", category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" },
        { name: "Beef", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" }
      ],
      group: [
        // group by "category" and then by "subcategory"
        { field: "category" },
        { field: "subcategory" },
      ]
    });
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: dataSource
    });
  </script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/OBAva

Comment: Thanks alot!! This is just perfect and works really well

Comment: Hi. Is it possible group together, not "then"? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because it was asked, and is implied in the question title: it is possible to group "together" and not hierarchically.  It requires a change to the data model so that all the grouping columns are held together in a single object.

In the datasource, the model and grouping configuration might look like

```
  data: [
    { name: "Pork", cat_group: { category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" } },
    { name: "Pepper", cat_group: { category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" } },
    { name: "Beef", cat_group: { category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" } }
  ],
  group: [
    // group by "category" and "subcategory" together
    { field: "cat_group" },
  ]
```

#### **UPDATE** for MVC integration:

If this is being done with serialized objects in ASP.NET MVC using an AJAX datasource, note that the grouping object must have value semantics (overriding `Equals` and implementing `==`/`!=`) as well as implementing `IComparable`.

Comment: Great MVC tip thanks!! The last part of the MVC is very important in the case of columns that are class objects.  Although remember to not use `==` within the override of `==` otherwise you get infinite recursion! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219261/overriding-operator-how-to-compare-to-null  So you need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461585/operator-overloading-equals/25461680#25461680