# What does this overload mean?

Tags: c#, equality, referenceequals

Can someone explain me what does this overload mean?

```
public static bool operator ==(Shop lhs, Shop rhs)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

I have never seen Object.ReferenceEquals in overload

Comment: `Object.ReferenceEquals` checks if the references are equal... ;) - In other words, it checks if the object is the *exact same object*, in terms of physical memory address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# .Equals(), .ReferenceEquals() and == operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869601/c-sharp-equals-referenceequals-and-operator)

Comment: Since the == operator of the Shop class is overloaded, the code avoids using it to test the parameters for null reference. if(lhs == null) would cause an infinite recursion and the app would simply crash with a stack overflow exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding == operator. How to compare to null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219261/overriding-operator-how-to-compare-to-null)

Comment: It's not an overload. An overload would be if you defined another `ReferenceEquals` with different argument types. (Which would be a bad idea in that case, but is useful with other methods).

Answer (score 36):

This overload was intended to compare two instances of `Shop`. It uses `Object.ReferenceEquals` to determine if one of the instances is `null`.
It cannot use `lhs == null` or `rhs == null`, because this would again invoke the `operator ==` and create an infinite recursion leading to a `StackOverflowException`.

If both instances are `null` it returns true (since they are equal).
If only one instance is `null` it returns false (since they are not equal).
If both instances are not `null` it returns the result of the `Equals` implementation of `Shop`.

Comment: you could also call `(object)lhs == null` and `(object)rhs == null` for the same effect

Answer (score 0):

It is an `operator overload` (of ==, not method overload of `ReferenceEquals`) to check if two instances of type `Shop` is of equal reference (that is, whether they refer to *the same memory address*).

```
bool result = shop1 == shop2; //shop1 and shop2 are of type Shop
```

When declaring `==` operator, you will also be required to overload its matching (or counter) operator `!=`:

```
public static bool operator ==(Shop lhs, Shop rhs) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) { //Check if the left-hand-side Shop is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)) {
            return true; //both are null, equal reference
        }
        return false; //lhs is null, but rhs is not (not equal reference)
    }
    return lhs.Equals(rhs); //lhs is not null, thus can call .Equals, check if it is Equals to rhs
}

public static bool operator !=(Shop lhs, Shop rhs) { //the opposite operator
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
}
```

It is also worth to note that `Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)` is used instead of `lhs == null` as the second will lead to another overload `==` being called till [infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion) which causes `StackOverflowException`.

They are used like this:

```
Shop shop1 = new Shop();
Shop shop2 = new Shop();
bool result = shop1 == shop2; //this will return false, since lhs and rhs referring to two different memory address
shop2 = shop1;
result = shop1 == shop2; //this will return true, referring to the same memory location
shop1 = null;
shop2 = null;
result = shop1 == shop2; //this will return true, both are null
```

Understanding this, you could even create something like this:

```
public struct MyCrazyInt{ //this will reverse the result of + and -
    private int Value { get; set; }
    public MyCrazyInt(int value) :this() {
        Value = value;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyCrazyInt otherCrazy) {
        return this.Value != otherCrazy.Value; //reverse this result
    }

    public static MyCrazyInt operator +(MyCrazyInt lhs, MyCrazyInt rhs) {
        int lhsVal = lhs.Value;
        int rhsVal = rhs.Value;
        return new MyCrazyInt(lhsVal - rhsVal); //note that direct lhs-rhs will cause StackOverflow
    }

    public static MyCrazyInt operator -(MyCrazyInt lhs, MyCrazyInt rhs) {
        int lhsVal = lhs.Value;
        int rhsVal = rhs.Value;
        return new MyCrazyInt(lhsVal + rhsVal); //note that direct lhs+rhs will cause StackOverflow
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
MyCrazyInt crazyInt1 = new MyCrazyInt(5);
MyCrazyInt crazyInt2 = new MyCrazyInt(3);
MyCrazyInt crazyInt3 = crazyInt1 - crazyInt2; //this will return 8
crazyInt3 = crazyInt1 + crazyInt2; //this will return 2
```

Answer (score -8):

It's very easy.
"NULL" actually is an object that resides in memory and has a reference and can be set To any object That is a subclass of Base "Object" class.

So above code first checks both "Shop" objects are equally null by comparing their reference value to "null" object reference, if both of them are equal to null so they are equal and return True.

If just first object is null and second one is not, return false.

And finally if first Shop object is not null then the code supposes that the second one is not null and compares their instance against Shop object to check they are equal.

And the main reason we nust use this way to compare null object is because you get a runtime error if you compare null or not instantiated object so we need to override the default "==" operator in this way.

Comment: Your casing is very annoying, also I'm not sure if _"'NULL' Actually is an object that resides in Memory"_ is the correct way to think about it

Comment: In the case Shop be a structure (ValueType) We can define them as Nullable Type (Nullable<T>) So in this case they can be so.

Comment: Finally (if Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)( Check, Does lhs refer to any object and if it don't refer to any object then if is true.