# Overriding Equals and GetHashCode doesn't necessarily override equality overloading operator

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public enum ClassType
{
    I,
    II,

}

public enum LocationType
{
    A,
    B
}
public class Person
{
    public LocationType LocType
    { get; set; }
    public ClassType ClaType
    { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Person obPer = obj as Person;
        if (obPer == null)
            return false;
        if (LocType != obPer.LocType)
            return false;
        if (ClaType != obPer.ClaType)
            return false;
        return true;

    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return LocType.GetHashCode()^ClaType.GetHashCode();
    }

}

  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var p1 = new Person()
        {
            ClaType = ClassType.I,
            LocType = LocationType.A
        };


        var p2 = new Person()
        {
            ClaType = ClassType.I,
            LocType = LocationType.A
        };

        bool isEqual1 = p1.Equals(p2);  //true
        bool getHashCodeNum = p1.GetHashCode() == p2.GetHashCode();  //true
        bool isEqual2 = p1 == p2;  //false
    }
```

I find that `isEqual1=true`, `getHashCodeNum=true`, but `isEqual2=false`.

I would expect that since I already override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, then the operator `==` should automatically follow the behavior of `Equals`, but this is not so. Any reason?

Comment: == only checks reference equality

Comment: Since the language allows you to override `==` for your class, it doesn't do so behind the scenes if you choose not to.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: mind that you do **not** override, but *overload* the `==` operator.

Comment: You need to implement : public static bool operator ==(Person person1, Person person2) .  Looks like same question be asked before in 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219261/overriding-operator-how-to-compare-to-null

Comment: You should overload the == (and the !=) operator as well . Follow [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx) guidelines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `==` is an **operator**. You can *overload* the `==` operator over two `Person`s as follows:

```
public class Person {

    //..

    public static bool operator == (Person a, Person b)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a,null) && Object.ReferenceEquals(b,null))
            return true;
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(a,null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(a,null))
            return false;
        return a.LocType == b.LocType && a.ClaType != b.ClaType;
    }

    public static bool operator != (Person a, Person b)
    {
       return ! (a == b);
    }

}
```

`==` and `!=` are pairs: you need to implement `!=` if you implement `==` and vice versa, otherwise you get the error:

> error CS0216: The operator `Person.operator ==(Person, Person)` requires a matching operator `!=` to also be defined

Now when you compare two `Person`s it should work. Mind however that you do **not** override equality operators, you **overload** them. So the *compiler* picks the `==` implementation (this is *not* done at runtime through a dynamic binding). As a result:

```
bool isEqual2 = p1 == p2;  //true
bool isEqual3 = (object) p1 == p2;  //false
bool isEqual4 = p1 == (object) p2;  //false
bool isEqual5 = (object) p1 == (object) p2;  //false
```

By default the `==` over two `object`s is *reference equality* so only if the two arguments are `Person`s here, we check whether the two persons are *equivalent*.

It is therefore probably better to use `Equals(..)` if you want to check equality with a dynamic binding.

Comment: At this stage, I'd usually recommend implementing `IEquatable<T>` too and putting all of the actual checks in there, as a central location. Then have `==` and `Equals(object)` call into it (after suitable `null` checks)

Comment: if (a == null && b == null) will result in infinite loop