# index out of range checker not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I would only like to assign the value to 'originalCOlumName' if there is a value in `dataStore.DataSourceDef.Rows[columnIndex].ItemArray[3].ToString();` if it is NULL or out of range, doesnt exist etc...I want to skip this part.
Ive tried looking at another example on [Preventing Index Out of Range Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113680/preventing-index-out-of-range-error)

but NULL checkers didnt work also tried

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataStore.DataSourceDef.Rows[columnIndex].ItemArray[3].ToString())
```

Comment: you may need to check against DBNull.value in addition to your check

Comment: If you're getting an index out of range exception you need to check the Length or Count property of `Rows` and then `ItemArray` against the indexes you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the length of both the Rows and the ItemArray collections to ensure they have enough elements to index into... Remembering that to get element number 3, the array must contain 4 items since numbering starts at 0. This would look something like;

```
var rowsLength = dataStore.DataSourceDef.Rows.Count;
if (rowsLength >= columnIndex + 1){
    var itemArrayLength = dataStore.DataSourceDef.Rows[columnIndex].ItemArray.Count;
    if (itemArrayLength >= 4){
        var theString = dataStore.DataSourceDef.Rows[columnIndex].ItemArray[3].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just do `columnIndex < rowsLength`.  No need to complicate it by adding 1 and also checking equality.