# overload == (and != , of course) operator, can I bypass == to determine whether the object is null

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

when I try to overload operator == and != in C#, and override Equal as recommended, I found I have no way to distinguish a normal object and null. For example, I defined a class Complex.

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}

public static bool operator !=(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Complex)
    {
        return (((Complex)obj).Real == this.Real &&
                   ((Complex)obj).Imaginary == this.Imaginary);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But when I want to use

```
if (temp == null)
```

When temp is really null, some exception happens. And I can't use == to determine whether the lhs is null, which will cause infinite loop.

What should I do in this situation.

One way I can think of is to us some thing like Class.Equal(object, object) (if it exists) to bypass the == when I do the check.

What is the normal way to solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check for nulls in an '==' operator overload without infinite recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should consider using the static Equals method in the operator overloads (which will call the instance Equals method):

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return Equals(lhs, rhs);
}

public static bool operator !=(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return !Equals(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Note: You may also check for `null` in the Equals method.

You can also read the [Object.Equals Topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=VS.100).aspx), which is a great source of samples.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'm not sure why.
And, why can Object be omitted in Object.Equals()?
And I didn't find why this can prevent the null problem in MSDN. (Does it check null first?)

Comment: You don't need the Object class prefix because Complex inherit from Object; Complex see the Object's static methods.
I don't know the internals of the static Equals method, but it likely check for null before calling the instance Equals method.

Comment: If lhs is not null the static Equals calls the instance method Equals on lhs.  If lhs is null Equals compares the references of lhs and rhs.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following at the top of your Equals override:

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null))
    return false;
```

The exception you are getting is probably a StackOverflowException because your == operator will cause infinite recursion.

**EDIT:**

If Complex is a struct you should not have any problems with NullReferenceExceptions.  If Complex is a class you can change your implementation of the == and != operator overloads to avoid the exception (Laurent Etiemble already pointed this out in his answer):

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return Equals(lhs, rhs);
}

public static bool operator !=(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return !Equals(lhs, rhs);
}
```

Comment: Actually it's Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It should work, thanks. :)

Comment: The exception still exists, since null.Equals() is attempted to be called.

Comment: I'd consider making Complex a struct instead of a class.

Comment: That's true. It just an example. And thanks anyway. (Actually Microsoft has already implemented Complex, so there is no need to create one in real life)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static bool operator ==(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null))
    {
        return Object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null);
    }

    return lhs.Equals(rhs);
}

public static bool operator !=(Complex lhs, Complex rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

Poor man's unit test

```
Action<Complex, Complex> tester = (left, right) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(left == right);
    Console.WriteLine(left != right);
    Console.WriteLine(left == null);
    Console.WriteLine(left != null);
    Console.WriteLine("---");
};

tester(new Complex(), new Complex());
tester(null, new Complex());
tester(null, null);
tester(new Complex(), null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks man ! that's very useful

Answer (score 0):

There is a better approach then using operators `is` and `cast`:

```
Complex c = obj as Complex;
return (c != null) && (c.Real == this.Real) && (c.Imaginary == this.Imaginary);
```

Here is a quick test concerning `Equals` operator override and comparing with `null`:

```
class Complex
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Complex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging doesn't step into operator's body:

```
var b = (new Complex() == new Complex());
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that c != null will cause infinite loop.

Comment: @LLS: Really? Interesting. Not sure that comparing with `null` will use `object` comparing operator. But maybe..

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it was a caution in the text book. And I did encounter this problem when I tried to recursively call ==.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud test for null in the == operator implementation. Otherwise, when lhs is null, you'd call Complex(null).Equals (I don't know for C#, but in Java this would be a Nullpointer Exception)

To test for null, I suggest something like:

```
if (null == lhs && null == rhs) return true
else if (null == lhs) return false
else return lhs.Equals(rhs);
```

So Object.Equals will be called for all == comparisons above.

Comment: You get a recursive call to the == operator.

Comment: Ok, interesting. Just being curious, how comes that operator ==(Complex, Complex) is called, when I test for null == lhs? How does the compiler decide that "null" is of type Complex?