# When overloading the equality operator, what's the best way to handle null values?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check for nulls in an ‘==’ operator overload without infinite recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion)

Say I have a type like this:

```
public class Effect
{
    public static bool operator == ( Effect a, Effect b )
    {
        return a.Equals ( b );
    }

    public static bool operator != ( Effect a, Effect b )
    {
        return !a.Equals ( b );
    }

    public bool Equals ( Effect effect )
    {
        return this.TypeID.Equals ( effect.TypeID );
    }

    public override bool Equals ( object obj )
    {
        return this.TypeID.Equals ( ( ( Effect ) obj ).TypeID );
    }
}
```

What's the most robust and cleanest way to handle null values?

I am not sure if I have to check for null for both the current instance (`this`) and the passed instance `(effect/obj)`? If I have null for the current instance (`this`), would the compiler still call effect.Equals or Object.Equals?

Also either way where should the null checks be done? I am assuming only inside the Equals methods, and not the equality operators (`==, !=`).

Comment: is it really a good idea to substitute equality of two objects with equality of of their properties? I can see that working with structs, but overriding == for classes seems like a breeder for obscure bugs.

Comment: @djacobson, thanks looks like a good answer over there.

Comment: I tend to agree with liho1eye.  Generally overloading the == operator is bad news.  I personally believe it's better practice to get used to calling .Equals() directly in your code.

Comment: @liho1eye, @Joan: There is a guideline from MS that overloading `==` and `Equals` for _mutable_ types is not a good idea.

Comment: @Henk: Thanks, do you know where it is? Btw this Effect type isn't mutable.

Comment: @Henk yes I know that, but my point is that it is a bad idea for reference types regardless of wherever they are mutable (value types should not be mutable always, otherwise you have other issues). I don't have a good example of top of my head, but it is very likely that various collection/groupping/hashing types/algorithms might be using `IEquatable.Equals()` or simply `==` and `!=`, which is likely to produce weird and hard to trace bugs with this class.

Comment: @liho1eye : string is a reference type (and a collection). The value-based Equality works OK for it.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, string is also immutable :)

Comment: @JoanVenge just corrected title from "overriding" to "overloading"

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `this` can never be `null`, at least not in code produced by the C# compiler.

Second, use the `ReferenceEquals` method to check for a `null` reference without possibly calling an overloaded version of `==` (or do `((object) sometypeinstance) == null`).

Comment: Thanks but if I have Effect e = null, wouldn't its "this" value be null in this case?

Comment: +1, the only correct answer here, seriously!

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has a snippet that provides a basic Equals() implementation for you. I'd follow that, unless you have a strong reason not to.

```
// override object.Equals
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    //       
    // See the full list of guidelines at
    //   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=85237  
    // and also the guidance for operator== at
    //   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=85238
    //

    if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // TODO: write your implementation of Equals() here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    return base.Equals(obj);
}

// override object.GetHashCode
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // TODO: write your implementation of GetHashCode() here
    throw new NotImplementedException();
    return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. Please correct it or delete it..

Comment: I believe it does answer the question. In answer to the question "how do you handle null values", the snippet answers "return false".

Comment: Sorry for being harsh, my mistake, but seriously, the catch here is when handling null values inside operator overloading and that is the question too. Even if OP does what you do, it can still give null reference exception inside overloaded `==` or `!=`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public static bool operator == ( Effect a, Effect b )     
{  
    return object.Equals(a, b);
}
```

The default implementation of Object.Equals() does the null checking for you.

In case you're curious, here's how Object.Equals() does it (courtesy of .NET Reflector):

```
public static bool Equals(object objA, object objB)
{
    return ((objA == objB) || (((objA != null) && (objB != null)) && objA.Equals(objB)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when I used a null value my type threw a null ref exception.

Comment: See the comments to your question - overriding == and != is not something to be done lightly :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pay attention to the first part of your message.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to check for nulls with every method that takes parameters making your class.

```
public class Effect
{
    public static bool operator == ( Effect a, Effect b )
    {
        if (a == null) && (b == null) return true;
            if (a == null) return false;
            return a.Equals ( b );
    }

    public static bool operator != ( Effect a, Effect b )
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public bool Equals ( Effect effect )
    {
            if (b == null) return false;
        return this.TypeID.Equals ( effect.TypeID );
    }

    public override bool Equals ( object obj )
    {
            if (obj == null) return false;
        return this.TypeID.Equals ( ( ( Effect ) obj ).TypeID );
    }
}
```

Other things to look out for are GetHashCode which should be implemented if equality is being implemented and the fact that GetHashCode should only be implemented on immutable properties, if this object is going to be used in a dictionary or similar object that compares items using the hash code.

Comment: Thanks, also this wouldn't compile, right? (return !a == b;)?

Comment: My mistake I missed a pair of brackets, I must be too used to the crutch of an IDE. I've changed it to !(a == b);

Comment: Np man, I am used to the IDE too much too :O

Comment: -1, this creates infinite recursion and never really works at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion

Answer (score -1):

Add this:

```
 public static bool operator == ( Effect a, Effect b )     
 {  
     return a is Effect && b is Effect && a.TypeID.Equals (b.TypeID);    
 }  
 public static bool operator != ( Effect a, Effect b )
 {         
     return !(a == b );     
 }      
 public bool Equals ( Effect effect )     
 {         
    return this == effect );     
 }      
 public override bool Equals ( object obj )     
 {   
    return obj is Effect && this == obj); 
 }
```

or instead of last put:

```
 public override bool Equals ( object obj )     
 {   
    if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(
         "obj", "obj is null");
    if (!(obj is effect)) throw new ArgumentException(
         "obj", "obj is not an effect");
    return obj is Effect && this == obj); 
 }
```

Comment: Better be careful, though. `==` requires you to also define `!=`. This could potentially result in mutual recursion.

Comment: If you do use that code it will be necessary to add the equivalent to the != method.

Comment: This will introduce a stack overflow, no?  == calls !=, != calls ==, etc...

Comment: @Charles: Chris is right; this is going to overflow.

Comment: Yes fixing it now... perils of trying to be too quick...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you should chech against null. Why are you afraid of that?

Remember that when you play around with equals, you probably also want to take a look at the hashcode method! Those two methods are intertwined.