# Why is a stackoverflowexception thrown in this operator definition?

Tags: c#, .net, operator-overloading, stack-overflow

Please see my comment in the code below. How should I check for the parameter to be `null`? It looks like `null` is being casted to `Foo` which essentially makes a recursive call the the `==` operator. Why does this happen?

```
public class Foo
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        if (f1 == null) //This throw a StackOverflowException
            return f2 == null;
        if (f2 == null)
            return f1 == null;
        else
            return f1.Equals((object)f2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        return !(f1 == f2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo f = obj as Foo;
        if (f == (Foo)null)
            return false;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are *using* the == operator in the implementation of the == operator - and it's on the same type. What you need here is Object.ReferenceEquals to test for null.

Comment: What type do you expect `null` to be in that `==` operation if not `Foo`?

Comment: @harold: I'm using it on `null` not on the same type.

Comment: @Ropstah the left operand makes it that type though

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion (a thread on the workkaround)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because the language rules say to.

You've provided an operator with this signature:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
```

and then - wherever this happens to be in code - you've got this expression:

```
f1 == null
```

where `f1` has a compile-time type of `Foo`. Now `null` is implicitly convertible to `Foo` as well, so why *wouldn't* it use your operator? And if you've got the first line of your operator unconditionally calling itself, you should expect a stack overflow...

In order for this *not* to happen, you'd need one of the two changes to the language:

- The language would have to special-case what `==` meant when it's used within a declaration for `==`. Ick.
- The language would have to decide that any `==` expression with one operand being `null` *always* meant the reference comparison.

Neither is particularly nice, IMO. Avoiding it is simple though, avoids redundancy, and adds an optimization:

```
public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, null) ||
        object.ReferenceEquals(f2, null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return f1.Equals(f2);
}
```

However, you *then* need to fix your `Equals` method, because that then ends up calling back to your `==`, leading to *another* stack overflow. You've never *actually* ended up saying how you want equality to be determined...

I would normally have something like this:

```
// Where possible, define equality on sealed types.
// It gets messier otherwise...
public sealed class Foo : IEquatable<Foo>
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, null) ||
            object.ReferenceEquals(f2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Perform actual equality check here
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return this == (other as Foo);
    }

    public bool Equals(Foo other)
    {
        return this == other;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        return !(f1 == f2);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Compute hash code here
    }
}
```

Note that this allows you to only bother with nullity checks in one place. In order to avoid redundantly comparing `f1` for null when it's been called via an instance method of `Equals` to start with, you *could* delegate from `==` to `Equals` after checking for nullity of `f1`, but I'd probably stick to this instead.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply!

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thank you for not simply writing a short response, and showing a nice full example, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well-explained! A good way to get caught out with this mistake is by following [this MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2224-override-equals-on-overloading-operator-equals#class-example), unfortunately, which contains the same misbehaviour... :(

Comment: What if `f1` and `f2` are both null? Your code would return `false`. Shouldn't you have checked `if( object.ReferenceEquals(f1,null) && !object.ReferenceEquals(f2,null) )` and vice-versa?

Comment: @DrewChapin: No it won't - it will return true due to `if (object.ReferenceEquals(f1, f2)) { return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

A bit old subject, but I reached this page, so it might help some people.
To keep the exact same behavior, but without stack overflow, I would now rewrite it as follow:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static bool operator ==(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        if (f1 is null) 
            return f2 is null;
        if (f2 is null)
            return false;
        else
            return f1.Equals((object)f2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Foo f1, Foo f2)
    {
        return !(f1 == f2);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo f = obj as Foo;
        if(f is null) return false;
        return f == this;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```