# How can i implement == and check for null in c#

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is “Best Practice” For Comparing Two Instances of a Reference Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104158/what-is-best-practice-for-comparing-two-instances-of-a-reference-type)
>   [How do I check for nulls in an '==' operator overload without infinite recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion)

I have a class called "Criterion" and i want to implement == operator,but I'm struggling with the following problem :

When i implement the == operator, I'm checking if one or both of my instances are null, but when i do it, it causes a recursive call for == and then i get "StackOverflow" (he he) exception.

Technically  i can implement the Equals operator and not override the ==, but the code will be much more readable if i implement the == operator.

Here is my code :

```
public static bool operator == (Criterion c1, Criterion c2)
{
    if (null == c1)
    {
        if (null == c2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    if (null == c2)
        return false;                
    if ((c1.mId == c2.mId) && (c1.mName == c2.mName))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Generally we say if (c2 == null) {...} rather than the other way around

Comment: dont do this. why are u doing this? stop!

Comment: have you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: @DarthVader Not very helpful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph overriding == for object equality is just politically incorrect.

Comment: what he needs to do is implement IEquatable<T> this is just wrong.

Comment: @DarthVader What do you mean "politically incorrect". The `System.String` class overloads `==`. Is it (politically) incorrect? The `System.Uri` class does it. Is it incorrect? When you write a `class` where some kind of "value equality" is natural, it's fine to overload `==`. That's the reason why the C# language offers the feature.

Comment: @DarthVader Bollocks. See the linked threads.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Bollocks up ya asss. dont let me do hood talking now.

Answer (score 11):

Try [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx):

```
public static bool operator ==(Criterion c1, Criterion c2) {
    var nullC1 = ReferenceEquals(null, c1);
    var nullC2 = ReferenceEquals(null, c2);
    if (nullC1 && nullC2)
        return true;

    if (!nullC1 && !nullC2)
        if (c1.mId == c2.mId && c1.mName == c2.mName)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for reference type validation.

Comment: you dont need `Object` in the beginning.

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks for the readability suggestion!

Comment: I would also use `ReferenceEquals`. But it is possible to specify which overload of `==` to call, just as for usual methods, so one can also say `if ((object)null == (object)c1) { ... }`. Actually it's probably enough to cast just one side of the `==` to `object`, not both, but I would cast both operands for clarity (or use `ReferenceEquals`).

Comment: this is wrong. this function is not doing anything useful. Instead it should impleemnt IEquatable<T>.  i hope noone uses this.

Comment: @DarthVader This is what the OP requested.

Comment: @DarthVader Of course it helps him, since his specific question was about overriding `==` operator. Saying that a working function is doing nothing useful is more "wrong" and "terrible" than a correct answer to a question.

Comment: if you do `ReferenceEquals(foo, bar)`. that is enough. `ReferenceEquals(foo1.mId, foo2.mId) ....` if the object references are same, checking fields is overkill as well. so your answer is just introducing reference equals blindly.

Comment: **Don't** use `ReferenceEquals` for the fields/properties `mId` and `mName`! That's wrong. Suppose `mId` were a value type, like `int` or `Guid`. You wold get boxing and compare two different boxes which always returns `false`. And suppose `mName` where a `string`. You would not check for `string` equality, but for equality of references, which is also an error.

Comment: You shouldn't remove it completely. You should probably use `foo1.mId == foo2.mId` and `foo1.mName == foo2.mName` (but it depends of the (compile-time) types of `mId` and `mName`).

Comment: Hm, this code is pretty horrible. The very first version of your answer had a much terser version that was vastly superior.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Feel free to change it yourself if I left off anything :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I changed it back, as my new code seems to have some controversy.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this code is pretty much what OP's original overload was meant to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
bool isC1Null = Object.Equals(c1, null)
bool isC2Null = Object.Equals(c2, null)
if (isC1Null ^ isC2Null)
{
    return false
}
if (isC1Null && isC2Null)
{
    return true
}
//your code
```