# Infinite recursion when overloading ==

Tags: c#, recursion, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

I have a class that I want to overload the == operator for in c#. I already have a .Equals override that works properly. When I tried to use my == operator, it gave me a null reference exception on my object (Person). If I try to check if it is null, it will in turn call the same operator to check it against null and create an infinite loop. This seems like a huge flaw and I can't figure out the right way to do it.

```
public static bool operator ==(Person person, object obj)
{
    return person == null ? person.Equals(obj) : false;
}

public static bool operator !=(Person person, object obj)
{
    return !(person == obj);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be return person != null ? person.Equals(obj) : false;

Comment: When comparing to `null`, you should use `!object.ReferenceEquals(person, null)` to ensure (and make clear!) that you're checking for reference equality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check for nulls in an '==' operator overload without infinite recursion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `(object)person == null` to force it to use the == operator of Object (or use `ReferenceEquals`). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: A 3rd option would be to use the static `object.Equals(person, null)` method.

Comment: @Servy: Though that works, that's taking advantage of an implementation detail of `object.Equals`.  Calling `ReferenceEquals` always does the right thing and is easy to read and understand, so that would be my preferred solution.

Comment: @EricLippert Can you call it an implementation detail if it's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) as such? “It determines whether the two objects represent the same object reference. If they do, the method returns `true`. This test is equivalent to calling the `ReferenceEquals` method. In addition, if both `objA` and `objB` are `null`, the method returns `true`.” Though I agree that `ReferenceEquals()` is clearer.

Comment: @svick: You make a good point; you can rely upon object.Equals to do reference equality first.

Comment: Oh my god, Eric Lippert commented on my answer. I don't even care if he was replying to someone else's comment. I'm going to take the rest of the day off.