# overloaded == operator throwing NullReferenceException with non-null operands

Tags: c#, iequatable

I'm trying to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface and `==` operator. The implementation below triggers a `NullReferenceException` when I try to use the `==` operator despite the fact that both operands are non-null. I've added comments to the minimum example code to show exactly where the exception occurs. What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;

namespace scratchpad
{
    class TestClass : IEquatable<TestClass>
    {
        public int data;
        public TestClass(int d)
        {
            this.data = d;
        }
        public bool Equals(TestClass other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return false;
            else
                return this.data == other.data;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            if (other is TestClass)
                return this.Equals((TestClass)other);
            else //Includes null
                return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.data;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(TestClass left, TestClass right)
        {
            return left.Equals(right); //This line triggers the NullReferenceException
        }

        public static bool operator !=(TestClass left, TestClass right)
        {
            return !left.Equals(right);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass tc1 = new TestClass(10);
            TestClass tc2 = new TestClass(10);
            Console.WriteLine("tc1="+tc1.data); //Prints "tc1.data=10" fine
            Console.WriteLine("tc1="+tc1.data); //Prints "tc2.data=10" fine
            bool isEqual = tc1 == tc2; //NullReferenceException occur here
            Console.WriteLine("isEqual="+isEqual); //Never gets to here
        }
    }
}
```

Edit (to clarify question in response to duplicates question flags):
I am not asking what a `NullReferenceException` is (I understand that) and I am not interested in `ReferenceEquals` as I need to equate the object's values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check for nulls in an '==' operator overload without infinite recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73713/how-do-i-check-for-nulls-in-an-operator-overload-without-infinite-recursion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your overloaded [equality operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-comparison-operator) is hit **three** times:

**First**, when called from `Program.Main(string[])` with the line `tc1 == tc2`, where `left`=`tc1` and `right`=`tc2`, which then calls `TestClass.Equals(TestClass)` where `other`=`tc2`.

From there, `other == null` now calls your *overloaded equality operator* a **second** time, where `left`=`tc2` and `right`=`null`.
Now, `TestClass.Equals(TestClass)` is called also a **second** time, where `other`=`null`.

And finally, `other == null` calls your *overloaded equality operator* for a **third** time, where both `left`=`null` and `right`=`null`. This now eventually causes the [System.NullReferenceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception) because **left** was null.

To fix this coding error, replace `other == null` with `other is null` in `TestClass.Equals(TestClass)`:

```cs
public bool Equals(TestClass other)
{
    if (other is null)
        return false;
    else
        return data == other.data;
}
```

Alternatively, as conditional expression (using expression body):

```cs
public bool Equals(TestClass other) => !(other is null) && data == other.data;
```

Answer (score 4):

The line `other == null` in `Equals(TestClass)` calls the equality operator, which calls `Equals(TestClass)` -- an infinite loop. On the second round, `other` is null, which leads to a `NullReferenceException` when you pass that to the equality operator as the `left` parameter.

You should use `ReferenceEquals(other, null)` or `other is null` instead.

Comment: This is useful for comparing whether two references 'point' to the same object, and might help others, but I am (was) interested in equating object values so I've accepted FlashOver's answer.